# The executable was signed with invalid entitlements [AIR]

Tags: ios, air

First before anyone suggests this has been answered elsewhere on SO, I submit that ALL of those answers assume you are compiling with XCode, which is not the case for me. I am using Adobe Animate to compile an Adobe AIR application and deploy to an iPad.

Updated Adobe air SDK to latest 32.0 and have tried re-creating my certificates and provisioning profile from scratch.

If I try to deploy directly from Adobe AIR  I get an error message

"Application verification failed"

If instead I publish an .ipa and try and deploy via XCode I get the following

[image]

If I furthermore check entitlements on my app.bundle I see

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>application-identifier</key>
<string>foo.domain.app</string>
<key>get-task-allow</key>
<true/>
<key>aps-environment</key>
<string>development</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

but checking entitlements in my Provisioning profile I see

```
<key>get-task-allow</key><false/>
```

Could this be the source of my error? If so, how do I get both these values to be the same?

Any replies welcome as I need to launch this!

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few ideas/things to check.

Check beta reports key is removed from the app descriptor.

When changing iOS certificates, delete the old ones via Keychain Access, then restart the computer before creating the Certificate Signing Request for the new cert.

Check that the new assets.cer has been created for the icons and it has been included in the package.

Check that all icons are present and all casing is correct in the naming on icon files as well as in xml.(e.g. icon and Icon)

Ensure path to SDK is correct. e.g. /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.2.sdk

If you still cannot install the app from Animate, try including the beta reports key, publish the app and upload it to TestFlight.